# Twitter API: media/upload 400 Bad Request: media type unrecognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

So I've got a website where a user uploads an image file (I've been testing with a 113KB PNG file). After hitting the submit button, the image data gets encoded into base64 and then is sent to a node.js server hosted on heroku in a JSON in the body of the POST request. The server then takes the image data and parses the JSON. Then, I make a POST from the heroku server to the `media/upload` endpoint using the node module, `twitter`. I've tried using it to post a regular status which worked, so it's not an authentication problem. In the example on the `twitter` module's documentation, they do this (raw binary, not base64):

```
var data = require('fs').readFileSync('image.jpg');
client.post('media/upload', {media: data}, function(error, media, response) { ... }
```

However, the way I'm doing it, I can't actually read a file -- all I've got is the encoded data from the JSON string. Anyway, here's what I've got:

```
...
let data = JSON.parse(req.rawBody).imageb64;
//console.log(data);
client.post('media/upload', {media_data: data}, function(error, media, response) {

  if (!error) {
    console.log(media);
    var status = {
      status: 'api test',
      media_ids: media.media_id_string
    }

    client.post('statuses/update', status, function(error, tweet, response) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log(tweet);
      }
    });

  }  else {
    console.log(response)
  }
});
```

I suspect the problem is because I'm passing in the data rather than the result of `readFileSync`. Any ideas on how I can do this without using it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a little note in the fine print of [the docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices) that may help:

> When posting base64 encoded images, be sure to set the “Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64” on the image part of the message.

The API docs aren't the best. There's a `media_type` in the examples but to be sure:

- `client.post` in [twitter.js](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/blob/296e82ede50ddace34ad64952fdfacfe8b1c65fc/lib/twitter.js#L239) calls `__request` with the `params`
- [`__request`](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/blob/296e82ede50ddace34ad64952fdfacfe8b1c65fc/lib/twitter.js#L105) does **not** set a the header

Does it work if you change the params in your call to `post` from `{media_data: data}` to `{media: data}`? If not, it seems like the only way to set the headers would be either open a PR or to try providing them as the default when you initialize the client: `Twitter(options)`. There are already some headers set [here](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/blob/296e82ede50ddace34ad64952fdfacfe8b1c65fc/lib/twitter.js#L33).

FYI - I've opened a GitHub issue for you. Join the conversation! https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/issues/292